RPI 4 with LS7366R encoder counter chip with incremental photoelectric rotary encoder
I have raspberry Pi 4 and it is connected to LS7366R, but I am not using the CS0 or cs1, am using any GPIO and controlling it (high/low) manually.
the encoder has A and B signals, and they are connected to the chip with a pull up resistor.
I am trying to write a code that gives me how many times the encoder rotates.
my code right now gives me values when the encoder rotates (positive to clockwise and negative counterclockwise) but the problem is these values doesn't make sense, because they change also based on the speed on the rotation.
https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Incremental_Photoelectric_Rotary_Encoder_-_400P_R_SKU__SEN0230
https://sdr-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/product_info/LS7366R.pdf
I got the code from: https://github.com/corncobb/LS3766R-Raspberry-Pi/tree/master
and changed it using ChatGPTt
this is my code:
import spidev 
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class LS7366R():

    # Constants
    CLEAR_COUNTER = 0x20
    CLEAR_STATUS = 0x30
    READ_COUNTER = 0x60
    READ_STATUS = 0x70
    WRITE_MODE0 = 0x88
    WRITE_MODE1 = 0x90

    # Modes
    QUADRATURE_COUNT_MODE = 0x01
    FOURBYTE_COUNTER = 0x00
    THREEBYTE_COUNTER = 0x01
    TWOBYTE_COUNTER = 0x02
    ONEBYTE_COUNTER = 0x03

    BYTE_MODE = [ONEBYTE_COUNTER, TWOBYTE_COUNTER, THREEBYTE_COUNTER, FOURBYTE_COUNTER]

    # Values
    max_val = 4294967295
    
    # Global Variables
    counterSize = 4
    cs_pin = 23  # Set chip select pin to GPIO 23

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Constructor

    def __init__(self, CSX, CLK, BTMD):
        self.counterSize = BTMD
        self.spi = spidev.SpiDev()
        self.spi.open(0, CSX)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        self.cs_pin = 23  # Reassign the chip select pin
        GPIO.setup(self.cs_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high initially
        self.spi.max_speed_hz = CLK 
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Set CS pin high initially

        # Init the Encoder
        print('Clearing Encoder CS%s\'s Count...\t' % (str(CSX)), self.clearCounter())
        print('Clearing Encoder CS%s\'s Status..\t' % (str(CSX)), self.clearStatus())

        self.spi.xfer2([self.WRITE_MODE0, self.QUADRATURE_COUNT_MODE])
        sleep(0.1)
        self.spi.xfer2([self.WRITE_MODE1, self.BYTE_MODE[self.counterSize-1]])
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high initially

    def close(self):
        print('\nThanks for using me! :)')
        self.spi.close()

    def clearCounter(self):
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Set CS pin low before sending command
        self.spi.xfer2([self.CLEAR_COUNTER])
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high after command
        return '[DONE]'

    def clearStatus(self):
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Set CS pin low before sending command
        self.spi.xfer2([self.CLEAR_STATUS])
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high after command
        return '[DONE]'

    def readCounter(self):
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Set CS pin low before sending command
        readTransaction = [self.READ_COUNTER]
        for i in range(self.counterSize):
            readTransaction.append(0)
        data = self.spi.xfer2(readTransaction)
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high after command

        EncoderCount = 0
        for i in range(self.counterSize):
            EncoderCount = (EncoderCount << 8) + data[i+1]

        if data[1] != 255:    
            return EncoderCount
        else:
            return (EncoderCount - (self.max_val+1))  
        
    def readStatus(self):
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Set CS pin low before sending command
        data = self.spi.xfer2([self.READ_STATUS, 0xFF])
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set CS pin high after command
        return data[1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import sleep
    
    encoder = LS7366R(0, 1000000, 4)  # Use CS0 for chip select
    try:
        while True:
            print("Encoder count: ", encoder.readCounter(), " Press CTRL-C to terminate test program.")
            sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        encoder.close()
        print("All done, bye bois.")


what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
